# How do I flatten a bag full of tuples into a bag?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, flatten

Like, say I have {{(1, a), (2, b)},{(3, c), (4, c)}}. How do I get {(1, a), (2, b), (3, c), (4, d)} from this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [FLATTEN](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator). Details can be found here.

```
A = LOAD 'data';
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN($0);
DUMP B;
```